# Scrapy not working with Crawlera

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been using Crawlera with Scrapy and its been great. However, I changed my API key in the Crawlera dashboard and ever since then I cannot get Crawlera to work. I contacted their customer support and they said the API key works fine. I decided to try getting Crawlera to work with the example from Scrapy's documentation. No luck. Scrapy is making requests to "dmoz.org" instead of paygo.com. I have scrapy-crawlera installed as well as scrapy.

Here is the log:

```
[scrapy] INFO: Using crawlera at http://paygo.crawlera.com:8010?noconnect (user: [my_api_key])
2015-08-10 19:16:24 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on [my_ip_address]
2015-08-10 19:16:26 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/> (referer: None)
2015-08-10 19:16:26 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-08-10 19:16:26 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 660,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 16445,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 11, 2, 16, 26, 990760),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'log_count/WARNING': 2,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 11, 2, 16, 24, 720987)}
2015-08-10 19:16:26 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Any help or ideas why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

```
#settings file
BOT_NAME = 'tutorial'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['tutorial.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tutorial.spiders'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'scrapy_crawlera.CrawleraMiddleware': 600}
CRAWLERA_ENABLED = True
CRAWLERA_USER = '[my_api_key]'
CRAWLERA_PASS = ''
CRAWLERA_PRESERVE_DELAY = True
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 32
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = False
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 600

# items file
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()

#spider file
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: _Scrapy is making requests to "dmoz.org" instead of paygo_ what makes you think that? Scrapy-crawlera uses Crawlera as an HTTP proxy so for Scrapy logs, URLs will still be "dmoz.org". To confirm that Crawlera is used, you can print `response.headers` in your `parse` callback, you should see some `X-Crawlera-*` headers

Answer (score -1):

in your setting.py file, you need to configure your "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES".

For example:

```
DUPEFILTER=True
COOKIES_ENABLED=False
RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY=True
SCHEDULER_ORDER='BFO'

CRAWLERA_ENABLED = True
CRAWLERA_USER = 'user'
CRAWLERA_PASS = 'password'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.referer.RefererMiddleware': True,
'scrapy_crawlera.CrawleraMiddleware': 600,
'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': "http://" + CRAWLERA_USER + ":" + CRAWLERA_PASS + "@proxy.crawlera.com:8010/",
}
```